# Error Undefined property: stdClass::$subscriber_options (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel

I have save data in json format i DB now i have decode data as

**My DB Query is as**

```
    $user_data = User::findOrFail($id);

  $attributes = DB::table('userdata')->where('id', $user_data->id)->select('attributes')->first();
    $user = json_decode($user_data->attributes);
```

If print $user it gives me output as

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [name] => test

    [time] => 2:34:00 AM


    [filter] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [options] => status
                    [conditions] => text
                    [values] => user
                )

        )
)
```

if i do `print_r($user->name);`
              it gives me name

I also tries as

```
$test = $user->filter;
     print_r($test->options);
```

It says trying to get property on no object 
I want to get

```
print_r($user->options);
```

If i do it gives error how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Since `filter` is an array you should iterate over it:

```
foreach ($user->filter as $filter) {
    print_r ($filter->options);
}
```

Or you can access it directly:

```
print_r($user->filter[0]->options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then please print:

```
print_r($user->filter[0]->options);
```